# Python: How do I search a string from one XLSX to be in another XLSX file?

Tags: python, excel, search, find, openpyxl

I have two XLSX files (Cookies and Cream), I want to know whether the values in each row in column A (in Cookie) exists in some row in column D (in Cream).

Using openpyxl, I have derived the following code:

```
for mrow in range(1, Cookies.get_highest_row() +1):
    for arow in range(1, Cream.get_highest_row() +1):
        if cookies['A' + str(mrow)].value == cream['D' + str(arow)].value:
               print(cookies['A' + str(mrow)].value)
               break
```

Even though this does work as expected, this takes a really long time to execute as cookies contains approximately 7000 rows, and cream has over 24,000.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not really familiar with any XLSX API, what type of objects are `cookies` and `cream`? Would it be cheaper to turn the required columns (i.e. A and D) into regular python lists and work with them?

Comment: @user3267581 That sounds like a good idea. The objects of Cookies and Cream are spreadsheets where each column can be accessed and tampered with.
How would I load 7000 and 24,000 items into a list from an excel sheet painlessly? and how would I compare the two lists?
Ideally, I would like it to tell me the following information(maybe a list in a text file?):
"These are the following 'strings' in which are in Cookies but not in Cream"

Comment: As I said I don't know what library are you using. Can you give any info with that? Maybe consider actually turning the columns into python `set`s, so you can easily perform difference and intersection operations easily. The lists seem small enough for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I worked out, but note that this does not use any special methods of the openpyxl package (working on that). It should, however,be enough to speed up your work. The algorithm is faster overall and avoids some pitfalls in openpyxl (memory allocation for ALL cells, see the warning about midway through: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html)

```
def findAinD(cookies, cream):  # assumes that cookies and cream can be treated as such in the for loop will fail otherwise
    A1 = []
    D1 = []

    for mrow in range(1, Cookies.get_highest_row() + 1):
        A1 += cookies['A' + str(mrow)]
        D1 += cream['D' + str(mrow)]

    A1.sort()  # Alphabetical
    D1.sort()  # ^


    for i, cookie in enumerate(A1): # Enumerate returns the index and the object for each iteration
        A1[i] = D1.index(cookie)    # If cookie IS in D, then A1[i] now contains the index of the first occurence of A[i] in D
                                    # If cookie is not, then the result is -1, which is never an index,
                                    #  and we filter those out before round 2 (not shown)

    return A1
```

Use this method, and analyze the returned object however you want by checking for negatives, filtering it, etc

Comment: Use `ws.iter_rows()` to loop over a worksheet, no need to worry about `max_row`. Likewise, use `ws.cel(row=1, column=4)` for programmatic access. Indexing was added for manual convenience. If you want to check membership then use a dictionary rather than a list as `index()` depends upon the size of a list.

Answer (score 0):

openpyxl does allow you direct access to columns, but you will still have to check the cells yourself. Your code would be something like this:

```
cookies = load_workbook("cookies.xlsx")
cream = load_workbook("cream.xlsx")
ws1 = cookies['sheetname']
ws2 = cream['sheetname2']

cookies_a = ws1.columns[0]
cream_d = ws1.columns[4]

for c1, c2 in zip(cookies_a, cream_d):
    if c1.value == c2.value:
         break
```

If you have very large files this will be slow. It would be possible to use the parsing code to create a reference graph between strings and the cells using them but you might be better off using something like xlwings to automate Excel and make it do the work.